# Rails add_test_data migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, sqlite

Just working through the Agile Web Development with Rails book and near the closing chapters of the book I had to rollback the db a few times using db:migrate VERSION=0 followed by the db:migrate command. However upon bringing the database back from the ground up, the add_test_data migration fails to add the test entries to the db as it had successfully done previously. Any Ideas? Im getting the following in the development log

`Migrating to AddTestData (20091111225948)
  [4;36;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mselect sqlite_version(*)[0m`

`[4;35;1mProduct Load (1.0ms)[0m   [0m
SELECT "products".id FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."title" = 'Pragmatic Project Automation') LIMIT 1[0m`

`[4;36;1mProduct Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT "products".id FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."title" = 'Pragmatic Version Control') LIMIT 1[0m`

`[4;35;1mProduct Load (1.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT "products".id FROM "products" WHERE ("products"."title" = 'Pragmatic Unit Testing (C#)') LIMIT 1[0m`

`[4;36;1mSQL (1.0ms)[0m   [0;1mINSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) VALUES ('20091111225948')[0m`

The db is SQLite3, Ruby 1.8.6, Rails 2.3.4 and im developing on Windows (cringe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using 2.3.4 I would use [db:seed](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) to add seed data.

Short of that I'd try renaming your sqlite database and running rake db:migrate again against an empty database. You might have to create a new empty development.sqlite3.

If neither of these work for you posting the contents of the migration would help.

Comment: Hi Andy,

Cheers for the tips, I transfered the code from the migration into seeds.rb. It turns out that the code was failing silently because I was creating the records using create as opposed to create! (which is what the Railscasts guy does). According to the trace, I had a typo in some validation code I had written previously. Problem solved! ah, the wonderful world of shopping cart applications :/